# SSRS error: Native compiler return value: "[BC42206] Maximum number of warnings exceeded."

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a report which has almost 200-300 textboxes and expressions with custom code. The report was working fine with no errors. But all of a sudden I got the above weird error. I tried to find and rectify the error in all ways, but could not. Please help me out, any valuable suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I suggest to *View* the *Error List* and have a look at the warnings to find out what one thing "certainly no one has changed". If you need more help, let us know about the warnings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not able to see the warning as well as the error list. It is just displaying the above message.

Comment: What a pity. So what tools are you using to "work on a report"?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017, Microsoft rdlc report designer

Comment: Click *Error List* in the *View* menu.

Comment: Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll.  

An exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll but was not handled in user code.
AN error occurred during local report processing


The above message is displayed in output window.

Comment: I assume you have googled `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException` and tried all the suggestions?

Comment: Yes I did. I have resolved the issue. Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.